Why can't we deploy to the app engine with nodejs version 20?
Since this morning we are not able to deploy to the app engine on GCP.
We recieve this kind of error message.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Error(s) encountered validating runtime. Your runtime version for nodejs20 is past End of Support. Please upgrade to the latest runtime version available..
This only occurs in env:flex.
Runtime: nodejs20. (this is supported by google)
Can anybody help me.
We have change the runtime nodejs versions in the yaml and in the package.json
Also previous working version was 17 and since yesterday it worked fine.
Also we have changed env:flex to standard. We can deploy then but or server application doesn't with our angular frontend.

I'm facing the same problem with "Go" uploads in flexible environment. It doesn't matter if I set the most recent version of go. Could it be a problem with GCP?

I'm also facing this issue in a flexible environment. Node 18 deployments work on a similar standard environment but on in flexible

Did you read the documentation?
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/runtime#newversions

I was facing the same problem, so I discovered that the problem was with my google-app-engine-deploy that was out of dated. You will need to update your pipeline to use the latest version then the process will recognize the runtime_config settings on your app.yaml.
Update your app.yaml following the documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/runtime
and choose a version of engine deploy to update your pipeline file:
https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/google-app-engine-deploy/downloads/?tab=tags
If you don't use pipelines and deploy the app directly using the gcloud CLI, you will need to update your gcloud version locally, then should works.

in your app.yaml seems like you need to change ur env:flex to env:standard.
runtime: nodejs20 
env: standard

this solve my issue, but i have no idea why.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
